# WCF failover with a single endpoint by using DNS Records

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Given a simple WCF client setup:

```
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding("wsHttp");
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("my.address.com/myservice.svc");
        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpoint);
        var service = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

"my.address.com" has multiple A DNS records (it is mapped to multiple IP addresses).
I want to provide failover by using these IP addresses.

I thought about creating a client-side WCF service which would act as a routing service, by using something like the following configuration for it:

```
<routing>
  <filters>
    <filter name="MatchAllFilter1" filterType="MatchAll" />
  </filters>
  <filterTables>
    <filterTable name="filterTable1">
        <add filterName="MatchAllFilter1" endpointName="myservice" backupList="backupEndpointList"/>
    </filterTable>
  </filterTables>
  <backupLists>
    <backupList name="backupEndpointList">
  <!--       <add endpointName="firstBackup" />  -->
  <!--       <add endpointName="anotherBackup" />    -->
    </backupList>
  </backupLists>
</routing>
```

But this requires me to provide multiple endpoints.
I want my client to try using all IP addresses for that domain name until one succeeds.

**Is there a way for the client to use a single endpoint (by using the domain name) but force WCF client to use a specific IP address for that domain name?**

Comment: Why don't you put the WCF service behind an nginx or other decent proxy server and let that piece of equipment handle the load-balancing / taking end-points out of rotation?

Comment: What if my proxy server fails? If I could achieve my requirement I eliminate the weak link.

Comment: You could outsource the proxy to Fastly or CloudFlare. They have scale and failover  and 5 nines availability.

Comment: I can. I still like to know the answer to my question - can I hint WCF client with  which IP to choose for a domain name?